# Authorization checks for editing attributes of a task

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

Model:

```
class Task extends Model {
}
```

with fields

```
protected $fillable = ['message', 'due_time', 'status'];
```

I've added special functions `public function getEditableStateForAttributeName()`.

In my helper function I check that if `method_exists($class, 'getEditableStateForFieldName')`, then I check the boolean value returned by this method to decide whether to allow editing this field.

Example:

```
if( ! $cls->getEditableStateForDueTime() ) {
    return "You can not edit field due time";
}
```

Real code:

```
private function isCreator() {
     $user = Auth::user();
     if($user) {
         return $user->id === $this->creator_id;
     }
     return false;
}   

public function getEditableStateForMessage() {
     return $this->isCreator();
 }

public function getEditableStateForDueTime() {
     return $this->isCreator();
}

public function getEditableStateForStatus() {
    return $this->isCreator() && $this->status === 'CREATED';
}
```

Is this a good way to do it or it is very bad design because of hidden dependency on `Auth::user()`?

What is a better way?

I do not want to put this logic inside controllers because this logic propagates to another models and is universal across application.

I've written some helper functions which facilitates validation of my models

Inside controller I simply write

```
createValidatorForModel(Task::class)
```

and it returns new validator with custom errors/custom attributes names/additional checks/etc.

Comment: It's working code. Part of it. I agree that question is mostly about design, not code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you say, you are hiding dependencies if you have `new` or call a non-pure function with the `x::y($z)` syntax.

One way to go around this, is to **acknowledge the dependency and take it as a constructor argument**, so that the current object doesn't care where it gets its user from, but it knows that it can call `isCreator()` or such. Some would advice you to take dependencies through `setUser(User $u)`-like methods, but that would make the object useless between its constructor is called, and until the `setUser()` method is called, because `getEditableStateForMessage()` and friends will fail in the meantime.

You should consider attacking problems like this from a TDD point of view: how do I test the current code without having to resort to real data?